ARP Packets dropped by Linux Bridge
I am having problems with a Linux bridge I created. Topology is as follows:
R1 (198.18.123.1) <--> ens19 [Linux VM] ens22 <--> R2(198.18.123.2)

Both R1 and R2 periodically send out arp requests looking for each other to the Linux VM. I can see those requests in tcpdump of the individual interfaces, and br0 (the bridge connecting the two interfaces):
17:50:36.539358 ARP, Request who-has 198.18.123.2 tell 198.18.123.1, length 46
17:50:36.929517 ARP, Request who-has 198.18.123.1 tell 198.18.123.2, length 46
17:50:37.549258 ARP, Request who-has 198.18.123.2 tell 198.18.123.1, length 46

The problem is, these requests are not being passed through the bridge - the far end routers are not seeing these requests come in and thus are unable to reply. I checked iptables and ebtables and nothing appears to be blocking the traffic:
virtual-machine:~$ sudo ebtables -L
Bridge table: filter

Bridge chain: INPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: FORWARD, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT

Bridge chain: OUTPUT, entries: 0, policy: ACCEPT


virtual-machine:~$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

My bridge is pretty simple, just created and given ens19 and ens22 as interfaces:
br0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::74f8:1ff:fe36:ef44  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 12:34:56:78:9a:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 7652  bytes 381804 (381.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 150  bytes 17642 (17.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens160: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.204.102.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.204.102.255
        inet6 fe80::e9d3:214d:db92:a38f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:50:56:81:dc:c9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30422  bytes 54605294 (54.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 23159  bytes 3419780 (3.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens19: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:81:5e:77  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10354  bytes 662164 (662.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10282  bytes 773917 (773.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens22: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:81:0d:dd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 10449  bytes 666034 (666.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10091  bytes 758696 (758.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens160 is how I connect into the linux VM, its the only one with an IP. As you can see, br0 is receiving lots of packets but not forwarding out very many at all.

What VM software (hypervisor) are you using – does it have options for MAC filtering ("allow promiscuous mode" etc)? Most do.

If you run tcpdump on the individual bridge port interfaces, does a capture on ens22 show the ARP requests that came in via ens19 and vice versa? Or do they actually stop at br0?

tcpdump on the individual bridge port interfaces show arp requests going both ways, both ens19 and ens22 can see arp requests coming in from 198.18.123.1 and 198.18.123.2

Using VMware Vsphere - I'll look into "allow promiscuous mode"

Checked the VM settings - I set "promiscuous mode" to accept, without any change. I also set "mac address changes" to accept, without any changes. I then set "forged transmits" to accept - which stopped the ARP requests from showing up in tcpdump for any interface (br0, ens19, ens22) at all.
